# Real Time Tracking System

Tags: node.js, mongodb, real-time

My client has 1000 taxi, he want to track every taxi location and see his display. My question is how to track all taxi information using driver mobile device. I am using mongoDb for database. 
I plan to solve this problem using develop a api and mobile device send their location after 10 seconds. but the problem is server is very busy that time and can not working properly using api. 
I saw firebase store client information realtime . I need to know its possible for me to work as like as firebase database using mongodb.

I am using nodejs for backend development . If anyone know any way how to store real time data please help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (generally speaking) track taxi in real time, the problem is your Internet connection may be poor due to low GPS signal, have really low latency sometimes, or even be down. Instead design two independent applications:

1. One, which will store current GPS location inside a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) queue locally
2. Second, which will flush the queue to a remote sever

This approach will ensure you will, eventually, receive all the positions without having to worry about dropped packets and other issues that may and will occur.

Instead of the TCP connection you can consider using UDP (or better DTLS) instead which is faster, but less reliable. If reliability is a must (doubt it if it is just a taxi), then go for TCP (or better TLS). How will you send or receive the data is just a detail.

Also make sure you authenticate the device before you store any data, especially if the connection between devices is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase as a real time database. Have a look at this link: https://github.com/firebase/geofire

But in case you want to go with MongoDB you can use MongoDB Geospatial Queries and use socket.io to enable real time behavior. 
For more details: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://socket.io/ for the real-time tracking system.
It is a JavaScript library for real-time web applications.

You just need to configure MongoDB.
There are many blogs which can explain to you how to set up socket.io with MongoDB.

Some of them are...

1. http://blog.slatepeak.com/creating-a-real-time-chat-api-with-node-express-socket-io-and-mongodb/
2. https://blog.feathersjs.com/building-a-rest-and-real-time-api-with-express-feathers-and-mongodb-12071e5417e1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to implement the tracking in frontend
But that is not good way and not secure, because drivers can send the fake request real time
You can use websocket method to implement the checking real time of taxies
[Please check this link](https://marketingaltimetrik.medium.com/real-time-tracking-using-node-js-websockets-redis-and-open-layers-41949d7c979c)

I guess this way is similar with your idea
I hope this way is good for you
Thanks